# How to solve Android MultiDex Apllication Instance Null Pointer Exception?

Tags: java, android, android-multidex

I want to do a core api service integration in my `Android` project.
My core service class is as follows:

```
public class TestApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    private static final String LOG_TAG_NETWORK = "GNetwork";
    public static JacksonConverterFactory factory;
    private static TestApplication instance;
    private OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpBuilder;
    private TestService testtService;
    private Location lastKnownLocation;

public static TestApplication getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance = this;

    Pref.init(this);

    okHttpBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    okHttpBuilder.connectTimeout(UrlConstants.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(UrlConstants.READ_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(UrlConstants.WRITE_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (BuildConfig.LOG_ENABLED) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor =
                new HttpLoggingInterceptor(message -> Log.d(LOG_TAG_NETWORK, message));
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        okHttpBuilder.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);
    }
    factory = getJacksonConverterFactory();
}

@NonNull
private JacksonConverterFactory getJacksonConverterFactory() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    return JacksonConverterFactory.create(objectMapper);
}

public void setupRetrofit() {

    String BASE_URL = "http://xxxxx";

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).client(okHttpBuilder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(factory).build();

    testService = retrofit.create(TestService.class);
}

public TestService getTestService() {
    return testService;
    }
}
```

Then I create an instance from this core class. But here my constant `getIntance` value returns null.

```
TestApplication.getInstance().setupRetrofit();
```

I can't understand that. `GetInstance` method always return `null`;

In my app `build.gradle` file is `multiDexEnabled true`.

How to solve this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never use instance of application like this. for get application instance you need activity and in your activity you can use

```java
    static TestApplication getInstance(Activity activity) {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = ((TestApplication) activity.getApplication());
        return instance;
    }
```

this will solve your issues but the way you implement retrofit and using it is not best practices. You can find better way that doesn't need activity.

Comment: maybe not best practice but when I add the activity to my manifest, it starts automatically when starting the application so getInstance is never null at all.

Comment: @Fatih the purpose of ```getInstance``` usage is yours. I just want to say there is better way for ```Retrofit```.

Comment: yes i know, thank you, but for now i will use such a way for `Retrofit`.

Answer (score 0):

change getInstance()

**from this**

```
public static TestApplication getInstance() {
return instance;
}
```

**to this**

```
public static TestApplication getInstance() {
instance=new TestApplication();
return instance;
}
```

and also remove this line from oncreate

```
instance = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

After Enabling Multidex

Replace With:-

public class Application extends MultiDexApplication {

```
public static final String TAG = Application.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    ApplicationHelper.initDatabaseHelper(this);
    PostInteractor.getInstance(this).subscribeToNewPosts();
}
```

}